# Android - smoothScrollToPosition inside a child Fragment in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm having difficulty in setting smooth scroll for `Fragments` inside `ViewPager`, nested in another `Fragment` which acts as their parent.

I set up this method :

```
public void scrollToTop()
    {
        this.recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
    }
```

For `Fragments` not in a `ViewPager`, but I don't know how to get the reference of `Fragments` inside a `ViewPager`.

I did

```
BottomLobiFragment activeLobi = (BottomLobiFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(utilities.lobbyTag);
```

to get the parent `Fragment`.

Code for a `ViewPager` (The rest are almost identical, difference is only at number of item, and constructor)

```
public class LobbyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public LobbyPagerAdapter (FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos) {
                case 0: return Friends.newInstance("Friends, Instance 1");
//                case 1: return Photo.newInstance("Photo, Instance 1");
//                case 2: return Activities.newInstance("Activities, Instance 1");
                default: return Friends.newInstance("Friends, Default");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            //return 3;
            return CONTENT.length;
        }

        private class setAdapterTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Note : Every adapter is located inside the parent `Fragment`

Comment: show the code of your adapter you used for ViewPager as well

Answer (score 0):

First modify your Adapter to this

```
public class LobbyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private ArrayList<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();

        public LobbyPagerAdapter (FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            mFragments.add(Friends.newInstance("Friends, Instance 1")); 
            mFragments.add(Photo.newInstance("Photo, Instance 1")); 
            mFragments.add(Activities.newInstance("Activities, Instance 1")); 
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            return mFragments.get(pos);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            //return 3;
            return CONTENT.length;
        }

        private class setAdapterTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Now in your fragment or activity which is holding the ViewPager & the adapter instance, you can simply do like adapter.getItem(1); example :

```
//Suppose your LobbyPagerAdapter instance looks like this in your code

LobbyPagerAdapter adapter = new LobbyPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

// And now you want to get the fragment at second position in your tab

Photo photoFragmentObject = (Photo)adapter.getItem(1);

// And now you want to get the fragment at first position in your tab

Friends friendsFragmentObject = (Friends)adapter.getItem(0);
```

Comment: Ohhhh so basically I need to make the `Adapter` into public class? And what's the difference between using my `getItem` method to return the `Fragments` and your method of adding one by one?

Comment: with your `getItem` method, you will always get the "New" instance of the fragments instead of the one that is inside the viewpager & you might end up with `NullPointerException`. 
so we only instantiate fragments in constructor & store them in `ArrayList`,
 so we can have the same instance every time we need via `getItem` instead of new one

Comment: Damn, so that's why my Fragments inside the ViewPager keeps refreshing, right? I'll change it when I return to it, meantime, I'm tinkering with other parts of the app, thanks! And btw, why `getFragmentManager()` not `getChildFragmentManager()`?

Comment: If you are saying about the fragment refreshing when you swipe them then it's another thing probably, you should put something like

`mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3); \\if you have 3 tabs`

& I was not sure where your adapter & ViewPager are placed so i just typed `getFragmentManager()`` :)

btw you can accept this answer if this helps you, it might can help others if they have similar issue. :)

Comment: Ohh not that, I don't want to do offscreen page limit as I am having memory problem which I haven't found the solution yet :(.. Oh yes! I forgot! It needs to be child..